# Changing Build Number using Powershell in TFS

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfsbuild

I'm trying to modify the build number for each build I run. I have a custom script that I use to modify a build number. I was wondering if I'm able to do this in Powershell in a Pre-build script? So far from what I've read is that this may not be possible. Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the XAML workflow.  We have done this where we use a custom Workflow activity to generate a build version number based on a major.minor argument and current date/time.  After you have generated the buildNumber you need to pass that into the TeamBuild UpdateBuildNumber activity.

Comment: Hey Keith, I saw that on the MSDN website. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I have been writing the code and I'm trying to reference an assembly of which my code looks like this:

$assemblies = ("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client") 

Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $assemblies -TypeDefinition $test -Language CSharp 

now, $test is basically my class that I'm going to use. Currently, the DLL is sitting in the same directory as the script in TFS. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using TFS 2013 the default build template includes hooks to specify a pre-build script.  You can reference a PowerShell script and use it to version your assemblies without ever having to modify the XAML workflow.

The [TFS Community Build Extensions](https://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/) include a few sample scripts including one to version assemblies.

You can read a more detailed blog post on how to configure this here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/07/24/basic-tfbuild-scripts.aspx